# remove a character from a column

Tags: sqlite

Example table:

```
  ID      RA      RB
  ------  ------  -----
  1       龍      龍 竜 龒
  2       齒      歯 齒 
  3       黽      黽
```

I would like to modify column RB so that it doesn't contain the character in RA.
Like this:

```
  ID      RA      RB
  ------  ------  -----
  1       龍       竜 龒
  2       齒      歯 
  3       黽
```

Comment: Can RA contain more than one character?

Comment: Each entry in column RA contains only one character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just [replace](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#replace) that character with an empty string:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET RB = replace(RB, RA, '');
```

Comment: Thank you.
("Comments must be at least 15 characters in length.")